# Removing duplicate entries in an SQL table?

Tags: mysql, sql

I did research but the answers were too complicated to convert to my schema and solution.

I have a table which I forgot to make a field unique in and now the insert has created lots and lots of items under the same field value. My table name is `queue_items` and the field is called `item` - how can I remove duplicates of `item` field?

I still want to be left with 1 item of the duplicates if that makes sense, but just delete any more than 1.

Here is what I've got so far

```
WITH CTE AS(
   SELECT `item`
       RN = ROW_NUMBER()OVER(PARTITION BY `item` ORDER BY `item`)
   FROM `queue_items`
)
DELETE FROM CTE WHERE RN > 1
```

Comment: try to create auto-incremental primary key, then you can query against it - check for minimum value / group per item or any other similar approach

Comment: Do you have a primary key? If not, do you care which record you keep?

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18932/how-can-i-remove-duplicate-rows

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have a primary key like e.g. `id` you could try something like:

```sql
DELETE FROM
  queue_items
WHERE
  id
NOT IN (
  SELECT MIN(id) FROM queue_items GROUP BY item
);
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest emptying the table and repopulating it:

```
CREATE temp_qi AS
    SELECT i.*
    FROM (SELECT qi.*,
                 ROW_NUMBER()OVER(PARTITION BY `item` ORDER BY `item`) as seqnum
          FROM `queue_items`
         ) qi
         WHERE seqnum = 1;

ALTER TABLE drop_column seqnum;

TRUNCATE TABLE queue_items;   -- backup before doing this!

INSERT INTO queue_items
    SELECT *  -- columns should be in the right order
    FROM temp_qi;
```

Answer (score 0):

Well that was s tricky one :) As far As I noticed you have a SQL-Table with Duplicate Entries, no Unique-Key (of course) and now simply want to get rid of the duplicates. I tried to recreate this using mySQL, which is not that easy for one can not DELETE / UPDATE and Querying to the same Table in mySQL per Definition.

Instead I had to follow this simple workaround:

1. Create a new TempTable, with the same structure as the original table
2. Copy every entry, to the new TempTable BUT group them by the duplicate_ID
3. DELETE original table
4. RENAME TempTable to the original table's name

In SQL you can do so by running the following queries - but make sure you have a backup, just in case.... :)

Workaround Delete duplicate SQL entries:

```
CREATE TABLE newTestTabelle LIKE TestTabelle;
    //make sure table was created successfully before next step

INSERT INTO newTestTabelle
    SELECT * FROM TestTabelle
    GROUP BY myIndex; 
    //make sure copy was successfully done

DROP TABLE TestTabelle;

ALTER TABLE newTestTabelle RENAME TO TestTabelle;
```

**Hint**: I found a similar solution and very nice documentation for that under following link (http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-delete-duplicate-rows/) - read for further information on topic